# Not displaying ads by ad banner from admob in android

Tags: android, admob

I want to display ads banner from admob in my android apps :

**what i have** :

1. In manifest add a activity -

```
    <activity android:name=".AdMobActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
      android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"/>

</application>
```

2 . In my apps layout -

```
<com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    ads:adSize="BANNER" ads:adUnitId="a150095f0ed0554" 
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" > </com.google.ads.AdView>
```

3 . add the jar file GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.1.0.jar  .

**What is the problem** :

Display add banner with a message in red color -

"you must have AdActivity declared in AndroidManifest.xml with with configChanges."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the official docs](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/android/fundamentals#adactivity), you'll need to update the manifest with this activity definition:

```
<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
          android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
```

and necessary permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

You'll need to set `target=13` or higher in `project.properties` so the project compiles.

Comment: Glad it worked.  Consider upvoting and/or accepting this answer so that others will know to try this workaround.